# How can i do "brew link fish"

Tags: terminal, homebrew, fish

I am using "brew install fish" to install the fish, but it gave me an error:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula
>   built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink .
>   /usr/local/opt is not writable.
>
> You can try again using:   brew link fish

So I did "brew link fish", however it is said

> Error: Could not symlink . /usr/local/opt is not writable.

The problem is i don't have /usr/local/opt on my computer, am i missing something? How can I link fish to shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alright. It turns out brew does not like sudo, but brew do need to run at "local", so I changed my path to local in terminal, then redo this, then it works.

> sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo chown -R (whoami) /usr/local
```